# End HTTP requests with '\r\n\r\n' or '\n\n'

Tags: scapy

I have seen both '\r\n\r\n' and '\n\n' used in http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/demo.html, but I am not sure which to use. If I end my HTTP request with '\r\n\r\n', I get 'Continuation or non-HTTP traffic' when I inspect the http packets in Wireshark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use '\r\n\r\n' instead of '\n\n' since that is the HTTP standard. The web server might just being lenient in accepting '\n\n'.